# How to make `git stash` refuse to smudge unstaged and staged changes?

Tags: git, git-stash

## Question

How do I either

1. make `git stash` *error out* if there are both unstaged and staged changes and I haven't specified either `--staged` (`-S`) or `--keep-index` (`-k`), or
2. make `git stash` default to `--keep-index` if invoked without the `--staged` option?

Ideally as a global config option.

## Motivation

Several times now:

1. I carefully `git add -p` just the changes I want to commit (sometimes with temporary edits to files beforehand, when I want to pull apart two atoms of change which happen to touch the same lines or adjacent line, which `git` struggles with), then
2. I think "I'll just quickly stash those other unstaged changes before taking the time to think of a good commit message", and so
3. I type `git stash`, wasting the work of step 1, because `git` does the dumbest thing a program can do in that case - destroys user information by default without opportunity to abort or undo, by stashing *all changes*, both staged and unstaged changes, blended into one diff without any distinction. (edit: the answers reveal `git` actually preserves the distinction when stashing, I just didn't know how to retrieve it)

Now if I was a computer program, I'd always just execute `git commit -m 'TODO: --amend THIS COMMIT'` before `git stash`, or I'd always remember to type `git stash -k`. But I find it more natural to think "I'll stash these unstaged changes real quick for later, then focus on the larger mental task of writing good commit message"

In fact come to think of it, I've been using `git` for close to a decade almost daily, and I have *never* wanted a `git stash` to stash staged changes, let alone fuse staged and unstaged changes back together. I can see how that could be useful if you're in the middle of staging one set of changes and then you want to stash the whole thing, but to me that's an extremely tiny window of time - most of the time, if I have staged changes and unstaged changes, they're meaningfully different pieces of change which I haven't finished separating out into the best atomic commits.

Comment: You can see the options available for stashing in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config. Beyond that you can write an alias and use that instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I've searched that page for "stash" and none of the options I saw do what I want. I would accept an answer along the lines of "there is no option for it, best alternative is [...] because [...]".

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_discussion), the index and the working tree are well separated into separated commits after the `git stash` command.

If your concern is to restore the index after a `git stash pop` I suggest using the `--index` option: `git stash pop --index`.

An alias can make transparent the use of this option:

```
git config alias.pop "stash pop --index"
```

(Edited the alias as mentioned in the comment)

Comment: !!! you're right! `--index` fixes it! `git init && echo foo >file.txt && git add file.txt && git commit -m foo && echo bar >>file.txt && git add file.txt && echo qux >>file.txt && git status && git stash && git stash pop --index` WOOOOOOOO! Nice. Thank you.

Comment: As a sidenote, you don't need the "!" (and repeating `git` at start) in your alias, since this is directly passed to git, no need for bash to intervene here. `git config alias.pop "stash pop --index"` should be enough.

Comment: One other side note: while I avoid `git stash` in general, I *especially* avoid `git stash pop` (regardless of options) as `pop` means *apply, then if you (Git) think the application went well, drop* and `git stash drop` is potentially very difficult to reverse. Git often thinks things went well, and sometimes I disagree. Of course my usual problem with `pop` is forgetting `--index`, so there's that too. 

Answer (score 3):

I'm sympathetic with the first part of the question, but I don't believe there is any such automatic option or configuration. I think the best alternative is Don't Do That — that is, if you're going to give a Git command, say what you mean, explicitly. That way, you know what will happen — because you *said* what should happen. (For the same reason I never say `git pull`, and I rarely say `git rebase` without saying `--onto`.)

At the same time, I'd like to push back sharply on the claims in the second part:

> destroys user information

Uh, no. Only if you think that `git commit` destroys user information. `stash` *saves* user information, in a commit (actually a pair of commits) — and saves it in a way that makes it easy to restore.

> blended into one diff without any distinction

That is not true. The index is saved as a separate commit. Thus it is possible to restore *exactly* the situation as it was, *both* the index *and* the worktree (except, of course, for the parts of the worktree that `git stash` doesn't touch by default, namely untracked and ignored files).

The way stash creation actually works is that the index commit has current head as parent, and the worktree commit has the index commit and the current head as parents. (In other words, the stash’s content is a merge commit!) You can see this by doing `git log` on a stash entry, and you will see the worktree commit followed by the index commit, either or both ready for you to restore.

<sub>Note that I am *not* defending `git stash`. It's weird and I generally try to avoid it (though sometimes it is a good solution to a specific problem).</sub>

---

**Addendum**: Demonstration that a stash can restore both the work tree and index:

```
% git status
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   a.txt
    new file:   b.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   b.txt

% git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on main: bc7bf2c startover

% git stash apply stash@{0} --index
On branch main
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   a.txt
    new file:   b.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   b.txt
```

Comment: "if you're going to give a Git command, say what you mean, explicitly" - I am trying to say what I mean - `git` is just designed to make what I mean *unsayable*.

Comment: Or rather, I was hoping that there *is* a way to say what I mean, and that I could configure or alias it so that *my* `git` would understand that I never mean the other thing - both of which ambiguously fit under the same language, since what I always mean is "stash unstaged changes", and the majority of the time, when I type `git stash`, that language says what I mean.

Comment: But since `git stash -k` is what you say you mean, I'm saying, _say_ that. You don't have to say it directly; you can alias it, as you yourself have suggested. But you can't alias it to `git stash`; you have to think of another command and remember to use it. However, I don't see why that's a problem. I use _lots_ of aliases.

Comment: Another question might be why you are stashing at all. You say _I think "I'll just quickly stash those other unstaged changes before taking the time to think of a good commit message"_ but I don't understand how stashing the unstaged changes helps you think of a commit message, and it doesn't affect what `git commit` will do at this moment, so what exactly is the point?

Comment: "That is not true. The index is saved as a separate commit." Yeah, I was starting to see hints of that as I've been doing some digging into this. even if `git stash` has the decency to not destroy that information, the `git stash pop` then destroys it fails to actually make use of that knowledge to restore that information, and after a `git stash pop` you have to be pretty aware of Git's internals to find it, if it hasn't already been GC'ed as an orphaned commit.

Comment: Anyway, if there is a human-friendly alternative to `git stash pop` that actually restores index+unstaged changes distinctly, that would be a great addition to this answer.

Comment: That is exactly what it _does_ do. If you say `git stash` and then immediately say `git stash apply stash@{0}` you get exactly the work tree _and index_ that you had a moment before. Indeed, that is exactly why this is a commonly used alias for "take a snapshot but make no changes": https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/tree/main/doc/git-snapshot

Comment: "That is exactly what it does do. If you say git stash and then immediately say git stash apply stash@{0} you get exactly the work tree and index that you had a moment before." What are you talking about?

Comment: It literally doesn't. Here I though this whole time you understood what I meant.

Comment: Sorry but it does. Wait a sec, I'll add a demonstration to my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean: you're talking specifically about when a file is partially added and partially not.

Comment: Yeah sorry here I made a minimal reproduction example: `git init && echo foo >file.txt && git add file.txt && git commit -m foo && echo bar >>file.txt && git add file.txt && echo qux >>file.txt && git status && git stash && git stash apply stash@{0}`

Comment: Also, I apologize for the my tone my comments have been increasingly taking on - lots of little accumulating frustrations, but I do appreciate your answer + reasoning + input.

Comment: Yeah, you have to say `apply --index`. You should accept the other answer! But I will proceed to include the demo in my answer anyway. :)

Comment: Cheers, I +1'ed yours as well already, despite the disagreements I was expressing, but I'll probably give it a couple days and then accept the one that feels most comprehensive.

Comment: No worries, I know how you feel. Added the demo to my answer. The important question is whether both answers are likely to be of use to future readers, and I think they will be.